# X axis and right box in stacked bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a plot like this

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(class = c("a","b","a","b"), date = c(2009,2009,2010,2010), volume=c(1,1,2,0))
df <- df %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(volumep = 100 * volume/sum(volume))
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = volumep, fill = class, label = volumep)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + coord_flip()
```

How is it possible to increase the text in the boxes in the right (class) and how to make the x axis have 0, 25, 50 and 100 values?

Comment: You plot `date` on the x-axis. `date` has the values 2009 and 2010. How should the x-axis have `0, 25, 50 and 100 values`???

Comment: @dario made the update with + coord_flip()

Comment: Still, the question remains, although slightly different: You plot `volume` on the x-axis. `volume` has the values `1`, `2` and `0`.  How should the x-axis have `0, 25, 50 and 100 values`???

Comment: @dario please see the update

Comment: FYI your code had a typo which I fixed: "volumep" was written inside the `mutate` as "volumnep". Also, what exactly do you want this to look like? You're referring to boxes on the right, but now you've flipped the axes so I assume that means bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = volumnep, fill = class, label = volumnep)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.title=element_text(size=22),
        legend.text=element_text(size=22)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,25, 50, 100))
```

[image]

## Edit:

I'd suggest recasting `date` as a factor:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(date), y = volumnep, fill = class, label = volumnep)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.title=element_text(size=22),
        legend.text=element_text(size=22)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,25, 50, 100)) +
  labs(y="date")
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question, just adjust the involved aesthetics, `y` and `size`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = 100*volume, fill = class, label = volume)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = c(3, 3, 5, 5), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  ylab("volume")
```

Another option is to `mutate` the values of `volume` first. In this case, there would be no need to manually set the y axis label.
After the question's edit, the code is now as follows.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(volume = 100*volume/sum(volume)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = volume, fill = class, label = volume)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = c(3, 3, 5, 5), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]